# ColdFusion CFIF

Tags: validation, coldfusion

I am new to ColdFusion. I'm trying to do some form field validation. However, my CFIF's don't seem to be working if the `form.name` and `form.address` fields are empty.

Here is my code:

```
         <cfif IsDefined("form.name")>
           <cfif IsDefined("form.address")>
              Your shipping address is:<br>
              <cfoutput>
                 #form.name#<br>
                 #form.address#<br>
                 #form.state#<br>
                 #form.shipping#<br>
                 #form.brochure#<br>
              </cfoutput>

           <cfelse>
              You did not enter an address.
           </cfif>   
         <cfelse>
              You did not enter a name.
         </cfif>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are only checking if the fields exist. Text input fields will always exist in the submitted form variables, even if they are empty. You need to also check if the field values aren't empty strings. Additionally, you should consider using StructKeyExists() instead of IsDefined() as it is more precise and in some cases performs better. So you could try:

`<cfif StructKeyExists(form, "name") AND Len(Trim(form.name))>`

This will check if the "name" form field arrived in the FORM scope, and that the value in that variable is at least one character other than a space.

Comment: As Carl wrote use **StructKeyExists** instead of IsDefined as long as you're 100% sure that you're looking for variable in the struct (luckily variables scopes are structs). The first function looks for the particular key only in the mentioned scope whereas IsDefined will look for it in all scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider checking for blank fields or missing input using Javascript or jQuery, notifying the user before they leave the page is considered courteous.

Comment: True. However, the question was about server side validation (not client). So the above is really a comment, rather than an answer.  (I realize you cannot [leave comments yet](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), just FYI).

Answer (score 0):

An similar alternative to Carl's answer is

`<cfif StructKeyExists(form, "name") AND Trim(form.name) NEQ ''>`

Answer (score 0):

I would think that if your are submitting a form set that the fields must exist so checking to see if they are there is unnecessary.

```
 <cfif (form.name IS "")  OR (form.address IS "")>
   We need your name and address to ship your item(s).
 <cfelse>
   Your shipping address is:<br>
          <cfoutput>
             #form.name#<br>
             #form.address#<br>
             #form.state#<br>
             #form.shipping#<br>
             #form.brochure#<br>
          </cfoutput>
  </cfif>
```

Minor issue but i never have used the form. part of a variable except in database writes.

Comment: This is very slow my friend, I recomend when you want to compare strings use LEN() or CompareNoCase() when you have two strings to compare.

CompareNoCase use HEGEX to compare and it is so fast!

My bests